# Adding objects from one array to another based on a condition

Tags: swift

The object has a simple struct:

```
struct Movie {
   
   var movieName : String
   var movieType: Array<String>
}

var parentMovieArray = [Movie]()
lazy var displayMovieArray = [Movie]()


func getMovies() {
     // get movies from API and populate parentMovieArray
}

 func filterMovies() {
    // segmented control setup where the index filters for movie type
}
```

How do I check if a string is contained in a Movie object in the parentMovieType array so that I can append that Movie object to displayMovieArray?

I am trying something like this but am struggling with the Apple documentation:

```
if parentMovieArray.contains(where: {$0.movieType.contains(self.day!)}) {
            displayArray.append($0)
        }
```

Comment: What is your condition? If you are looking for an exact match then do `displayMovieArray = parentMovieArray.filter { $0.movieType.contains(self.day) }`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Should have known this exists in Swift since I used the same on Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a swift expert, but it sound like you're looking for the filter method, implemented in most higher level languages these days, take a look at this link for swift:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter

This makes a new array based on some predicate

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` to create the array of items you'd like to append, and then append them to the other array using `append(contentsOf:)`:

```
let filtered = parentMovieArray.filter { $0.movieType.contains(self.day!) }
displayMovieArray.append(contentsOf: filtered)
```

You could do this in one line:

```
displayMovieArray.append(contentsOf: parentMovieArray.filter { $0.movieType.contains(self.day!) })
```

but it isn't really necessary.